# Could not find function "cbind.na"

Tags: r

I am using R:

```
library(qpcR)
final<-cbind.na(datum_seq, amb.temp)
Error: could not find function "cbind.na"
```

I have looked on the internet, and it suggests that I need to have the up to date version of R and qpcr package.

Confirmed in the `sessionInfo()`, I have the latest version. Could there another reason why it cannot find the function?

```
R version 3.1.2 (2014-10-31)
Platform: i386-w64-mingw32/i386 (32-bit)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United Kingdom.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United Kingdom.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United Kingdom.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                           
[5] LC_TIME=English_United Kingdom.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] plyr_1.8.1        qpcR_1.4-0        Matrix_1.1-4      robustbase_0.92-3 rgl_0.95.1201    
[6] minpack.lm_1.1-8  MASS_7.3-35      

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] DEoptimR_1.0-2  grid_3.1.2      lattice_0.20-29 Rcpp_0.11.2     tools_3.1.2
```

Answer (score 7):

`cbind.na` is an internal variable to the `qpcR` package. If you must call this function directly, you can do so using `qpcR:::cbind.na`.

See `help(':::')` for details on internal and external variables.

Before using this, note the following (from the help page):

"It is typically a design mistake to use `:::` in your code since the corresponding object has probably been kept internal for a good reason. Consider contacting the package maintainer if you feel the need to access the object for anything but mere inspection."

Comment: having a hard time getting this to work in a large list, saw this solution but I'm getting 'could not find function': do.call(qpcR:::cbind.na, lapply(df, zoo::na.trim))